# Android options disappeared after switching SDK and workspace folder

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Hello everyone i have got a strange error, actually it s not even an error.
I have just switched my workspace folder and changed the sdk path and now i haven't the android options in my eclipse. For examples if i press import or new i have just java project, java class ecc.  Not more android project, export to android app or stuff like that.
I have no idea what happened android sdk seems loaded theres no error linked to missing libraries or anything strange.
What's happened?

Already tried to delete android support library and re-installed but doesn't work